# Не вызывается виртуальный деструктор производного класса

Tags: c++, исключения, c++17, утечка-памяти, деструктор

Есть решение, где динамическая библиотека (SharedLibrary) предоставляет интерфейс (абстрактный класс), а другой проект - его реализацию (производный класс). Концепция минимального примера:

[image: концептуальная структура решения]

Класс `Website` выделяет 64 килобайта для буфера, куда помещает URL адрес. Далее, не покидая конструктор, симулируется вызов исключения. Ожидается, что деструктор `Website` будет вызван, однако вызывается только деструктор базового класса `InternetResource`:

```
Website::ctor
InternetResource::dtor
main::catch 'Oops!'
```

Следовательно, выделенная память не освобождается:

[image: отладка утечки памяти после ожидаемого удаления экземпляра Website]

### Решение

##### Исходный код

```cpp
//
// Application/Main.cpp
//

#include <iostream>

#include "Website.hpp"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        __debugbreak(); // for heap snapshot (1)
        Website site("https://stackoverflow.com"); // throws
        return 1; // unattainable
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout
            << "main::catch '"
            << e.what()
            << "'"
            << std::endl;
    }
    __debugbreak(); // for heap snapshot (2)
    return 0;
}

//
// Application/Website.hpp
//

#pragma once

#include <SharedLibrary/InternetResource.hpp>

class Website : public InternetResource
{
public:
    Website(const char* url);

    virtual ~Website();

    void* Buffer = nullptr;
};

//
// Application/Website.cpp
//

#include "Website.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

Website::Website(const char* url)
{
    std::cout << "Website::ctor" << std::endl;
    this->Buffer = malloc(1 << 16); // 64 kB
    memcpy_s(this->Buffer, 1 << 16, url, strlen(url));
    throw std::exception("Oops!");
}

Website::~Website()
{
    std::cout << "Website::dtor" << std::endl;
    free(this->Buffer);
    this->Buffer = nullptr;
}

//
// SharedLibrary/Dll.hpp
//

#pragma once

#ifdef SHARED_LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#   define SHARED_LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define SHARED_LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//
// SharedLibrary/InternetResource.hpp
//

#pragma once

#include "Dll.hpp"

class SHARED_LIBRARY_API InternetResource
{
public:
    virtual ~InternetResource();
};

//
// SharedLibrary/InternetResource.cpp
//

#include "InternetResource.hpp"

#include <iostream>

InternetResource::~InternetResource()
{
    std::cout << "InternetResource::dtor" << std::endl;
}
```

```lua
--
-- Premake5.lua
--
workspace "WhatTheDtor"
    location("Build/")

    configurations { "Debug" }
    platforms { "x86" }

function cpp_commons()
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    
    defines { "DEBUG" }
    symbols "On"

    runtime "Debug"
    staticruntime "Off" -- /MDd

    exceptionhandling ("Default") -- /EHsc
end

project "SharedLibrary"
    kind "SharedLib"
    cpp_commons()
    
    files { "./SharedLibrary/**.cpp", "./SharedLibrary/**.hpp" }
    
    defines { "SHARED_LIBRARY_EXPORTS" }

project "Application"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    cpp_commons()
    
    files { "./Application/**.cpp", "./Application/**.hpp" }

    includedirs { "." }
    dependson { "SharedLibrary" }
    links { "SharedLibrary" }
```

##### Воспроизведение

1. Соберите файлы по `Application` и `SharedLibrary`.
2. Используйте premake5 для создания файлов решения.

```
premake5 vs2022
```

2. Откройте './Build/WhatTheDtor.sln'.
3. Соберите и начните отладку с профилированием кучи.
4. Сделайте два снимка кучи на вшитых точках останова.

Вот и все. Здесь вы можете увидеть 64 килобайта неосвобожденной памяти.

Comment: Вы тут давно, должны знать про [mcve]. Зачем так сложно? Несколько файлов с кодом, DLL, и premake-файл, если все прекрасно умещается в один .cpp-шник?

Comment: *"Ожидается, что деструктор Website будет вызван"* - он не будет вызван, так как объект будет считаться созданным только после возврата из конструктора. Подъобъект базового класса был создан - вот для него автоматически вызван деструктор.

Comment: `memcpy_s` не копирует ноль в конце строки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, изначально я думал, что проблема возникает из-за структуры решения, потому минимальный пример сделан с двумя проектами.

Comment: @user7860670, скорее этого ожидал я - не знал об такой особенности unwinding'а на момент написания.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, так и задумано; иначе, зачем мне хранить строку через пустой указатель? Это минимальный пример, но согласен, что добавив memcpy_s я немного отошел от темы.

Comment: @ShamusRezol Так вы же написали ответ одновременно с вопросом. Значит цель была поделиться знаниями, чтобы можно было потом ссылаться на этот вопрос, когда кто-то не будет знать, что деструктор в такой ситуации не вызывается. Представьте, вы отправляете сюда новичка, а тут ворох информации про DLL и прочее.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен - стоило бы удалить вопрос из-за - теперь уже понимаю - неминимального примера. Ответ нашел перед публикацией, и не жалею, что опубликовал, так как нашел интересные ресурсы в комментариях и ответах. С другой стороны, до написания по теме вопроса я не мог найти про stack unwinding, из-за чего вопрос и существует - мне казалось, что виртуальный деструктор должен быть вызван в любом случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже пример как можно сделать `void *` буфер, который будет освобождён нормально, если конструктор бросит исключение. `void *` спрятан в `unique_ptr`.

Общая идея - поля сложных объектов должны сами за собой ухаживать. Тогда компилятор создаст корректный код обрабатывающий исключения в конструкторе.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void freeVoid(void* data) {
    cout << "freeVoid\n";
    free(data);
}

class Website {
public:
    Website(const char* url) : buffer(malloc(1 << 16), freeVoid) {
        cout << "Website::ctor\n";
        memcpy(buffer.get(), url, strlen(url) + 1);
        // cout << static_cast<char *>(buffer.get()) << '\n';
        throw exception();
    }

    virtual ~Website() {
        cout << "Website::dtor\n";
    }

    unique_ptr<void, decltype(freeVoid) *> buffer;
};

int main() {
    try {
        Website w("site");
    } catch (exception &e) {
        cout << "caught\n";
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ website.cpp && ./a.out 
> Website::ctor
> freeVoid
> caught
> ```

Comment: `decltype(freeVoid) *` как deleter - неэффективно, хранится лишний указатель. Дешевле `std::integral_constant<decltype(&freeVoid), &freeVoid>` - этот не занимает места.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я показал принцип самодостаточности полей в объекте. Это только демо.

Answer (score -3):

В документации сказано:

> … the process of unwinding the stack begins. This involves the destruction of
> all automatic objects that were fully constructed—but not yet
> destructed—between the beginning of the try block that is associated with the
> catch handler and the throw site of the exception.
>
> [MSDN: Exceptions and Stack Unwinding in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exceptions-and-stack-unwinding-in-cpp?view=msvc-170) [п.5]

Иными словами, если исключение возникает в конструкторе, то нет никакого иного способа освободить ресурсы, кроме как поместить весь конструктор в try-catch. Например:

```cpp
Website::Website(const char* url)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Website::ctor" << std::endl;
        this->Buffer = malloc(1 << 16); // 64 kB
        memcpy_s(this->Buffer, 1 << 16, url, strlen(url));
        throw std::exception("Oops!");
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "**forcing dtor from ctor**" << std::endl;
        this->~Website();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. `this->~Website();` - на грани фола. Есть стойкое подозрение, что это UB, потому что объект еще полностью не сконструирован. Лучше отдельную функцию под это. 2. *"нет никакого иного способа"* Есть, называется [scope guard](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard). Он быстрее (судя по [этому](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/SC22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1676r0.pdf)), и еще хорош тем, что если исключение не ловят и вы генерируете крашдамп, он показывает на оригинальный throw, а не на этот второй. Или, еще лучше, просто использовать `std::string`...

Comment: Ужасный ответ. Кошмарный. Просто справочник ложной информации и вредных советов по конструированию в C++.

Comment: Вызвав деструктор, я не пытался сделать что-то хорошее, а только максимизировал компактность.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, разумеется, лучше отдельную функцию. ScopeGuard - может быть, но, кажется, использовать Deleter из unique_ptr (ответ @StanislavVolodarskiy) будет лучше, чем создавать по структуре для каждого поля.

Comment: @ShamusRezol Не понял про "по структуре для каждого поля". Если пользоваться стандартными классами можно (`unique_ptr`), то почему просто не хранить строку в `std::string`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Buffer - просто пример; пожалуйста, хватит об строках - речь не о них. Вместо него в основном решении через ручное связывание на стороне другой DLL библиотеки создается экземпляр, однако если в конструкторе возникает исключение, то экземпляр не удаляется и обработчик DLL библиотеки не освобождается. Поэтому очень даже можно использовать unique_ptr, но вот как использовать ScoreGuard? Для каждого поля создать по структуре, которая гарантирует, что ресурс будет освобожден при исключении, и отпущен создателю в ином случае? Вариант с unique_ptr мне кажется лучше в этом контексте.

Comment: Guard пишется как макрос в конструкторе. Он не добавляет полей в класс. А-ля `Website() {Buffer = malloc(42); SCOPE_GUARD_ON_THROW{free(Buffer);}; memcpy(...); throw ...;}`. Вечером могу сделать полноценный ответ.